# Cannot get esleif to return correct value

Tags: if-statement

I have tried the following but cannot get it to work as it should.The first if works if area1 >=45 but if area1 = 41 or 42, it returns 15.25. Please help. Thank you.

```
if (area1 >= 45) {
    cost =(((area1 - 45)*0.144)+18.5);
}
else if (area1 = 41) {
    cost = 15.25;
}
else if (area1 = 42) {
    cost = 16;
}
else {
    cost = 10;
}
```

Comment: What language are you using here? You're also using assignment operators rather than comparison operators in your example

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` instead of `=` which is assignment operator in most languages:

```js
let area1 = 23;
let cost = -12;

if (area1 >= 45) {
cost =(((area1 - 45)*0.144)+18.5)
}
else if (area1 == 41) {
cost = 15.25
}
else if (area1 == 42) {
cost = 16
}
else {
cost = 10;
}
    
console.log(cost)
```